# Error while trying to install CouchDB

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, couchdb

I kept getting this error while I am trying to install CouchDB, may I know why? I am trying to install CouchDB into my cordova mobile app in Microsoft Visual Studio.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vVXT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find your python executable. You need to add `PYTHON` with the path to the executable to your enviroment variables.

Comment: however, it doesn't state which version of python right? so does it mean either 3 or 2 works just fine?

Comment: @Alvin According to [the requirements](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/install/windows.html#dependencies) Python >= 2.7 should work.

Comment: trying out after installing 2.7 Python, will come back again after testing, thank you!